# Is the phrase "when arrived home" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

My question is whether "when arrived home" is used correctly in the following sentence:

> I'd always heard "We are the champions" playing loudly **when arrived home**.

Comment: No, it isn't - you need to say _who_ had arrived at home.

Comment: No, it isn't - you need to say *when **arriving** home.*

Comment: No, it isn't. Who exactly do you think is arriving in such a sentence?

Comment: Correct use of "when" is *when + **subject + verb-with-tense***. This, however, is *when + **verb-with-tense*** with no subject, so bad grammar.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't - you need to say who had arrived at home. (KB)

If it was *you* who had arrived at home you would need to say when arriving home (FF)

Answer (score 0):

No. Correct structure for a "when" clause is: [*when + **subject + verb-with-tense***]. This, however, is [*when + **verb-with-tense***], with no subject, so bad grammar.